# Can I use my Bedrock skin in the Java Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a skin on the Windows 10/Bedrock Edition of the game that I would like to use for my Java Edition. I made the skin in the skin customizer within the game.
Is there a way to download or save the skin?

Comment: Is this a custom uploaded skin, or a skin from a skin pack? Also, which platform?

Comment: @aytimothy The skin is made in the in-game skin editor, and I play on mobile, Xbox, and Windows 10 edition.

Comment: I can already straight away say that most of the "cool" stuff is incompatible with Java edition purely because they add custom models to the character.

Comment: It's a regular skin, the only thing it has is a second layer, which I know is compatible with java. I just need to know how to download it, if I can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took a while but I did find this method:

First you have to join a server that has Floodgate 2.0 on it (for example the GeyserMC test server: test.geysermc.org (Bedrock port 19132)). You can do it without Floodgate 2.0, but that just makes it harder. Make sure to replace everything in *asterisks* with your info.

Then we need to find your xuid. This can be done using: https://api.geysermc.org/v2/xbox/xuid/*gamertag*

This will give you your xuid.
You can use that xuid for the following endpoint: https://api.geysermc.org/v2/skin/*xuid*

This will give you quite a bit of info, but you're interested in `texture_id`.
Then you can go to http://textures.minecraft.net/texture/*texture_id*

You can download that image and use it for your mc acc

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant. Also to add: If you see blanks, it's probably because you didn't do the first step (log onto a server with Floodgate)

Comment: Just an update (Oct 2021): It's broken (Geyser servers are down)

Comment: Just a note, if you have done this before, please skip to https://api.geysermc.org/v1/xbox/xuid/*gamertag*
and follow all remaining steps. It should still work.

Comment: Worked for me after updating "v1" to "v2" in all the api paths

Answer (score 9):

## tl;dr - Yes*

In Bedrock, unlike Java Edition, skins are a little messy; there's several types of skins available;

## Regular Skins

If you used an imported skin, you can find them in `[Data Root]\minecraftpe\custom.png` of your internal storage. On:

- **Windows 10**, this is: `%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\`
- **Android**, this is: `/data/data/com.mojang.minecraftpe/files/`
- **iOS** (you can access a sandboxed version of this via iTunes Sync), but the actual file location is: `/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/com.mojang.minecraftpe` or `/Apps/com.mojang.minecraftpe/Documents/games/com.mojang/` (depending on whether you are using sanboxed or rooted/jailbroken).

## Store Skins

There is [this workaround](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/385166/75275) (scroll up or down, depending on your sort settings) that allows you to access your skin, if it is a standard model skin.

However, some skins introduce custom models and higher texture resolution which cannot be transferred over to Minecraft Java Edition.

You can find them in the `premium_cache` folder, and under `skins` of your Minecraft storage directory, as above. However, they are encrypted.

There are however [mods](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/re-skin) that allow the usage of higher resolution skins, but must follow standard model formats (means no custom models or parts), should you get them decrypted.

Edit: It is possible to get skins of this type through custom add-ons, which are basically the same, but obviously not store-bought.

## Character Builder

First of all, this is a little more trickier. For most of the parts in Bedrock edition, they add extra geometry to your character. This means you can't directly transfer it to a Java Edition character. Instead, you'll probably have to recreate it using the textures, which are also found in the `premium_cache` folder, under `persona`.

## How do I decrypt?

> "Windows does not recognize this file format."

You don't. Or at least, you are not supposed to be able to decrypt them due to DRM. You could try recreating it from screenshots/eye.

Answer (score 4):

As of right now, Diehe's solution does not work. There is another way to access a bedrock skin in Minecraft through GeyserMC/Floodgate. It requires a Java account and a Bedrock account.

1. Log into any server that uses GeyserMC/Floodgate on *both* Java and Bedrock. I used `test.geysermc.org`.
2. Check that, from the Java player's perspective, the Bedrock player has the desired skin. It may take several hours to a day for a skin to display properly after the Bedrock player logs into a GeyserMC/Floodgate server for the first time<sup>1</sup>.
3. Once you have confirmed that you see the skin that you want, close the games and enter the Java Minecraft directory. From `%appdata%/.minecraft/assets/skins`, there exist folders containing every skin that has been downloaded by your client. Sort by date modified and open the latest folder. There may be more than one from the server you joined depending on the number of players present.
4. Add `.png` to the end of the file in the folder. Open it in an image viewing software to confirm if it is the skin you're looking for. If not, check more folders.

**If you want to convert more than one skin**, it may be necessary to join a new server for each individual skin.

I was able to get a basic skin from the Microsoft Store for use in Java using these exact steps. Hope this helps!

---

<sup>1</sup> From what I understand, there is a third-party service used by Geyser that adds the Java representations of the skins of Bedrock clients to a queue. The skins are put onto real Java Minecraft accounts to be uploaded onto the Mojang servers. If you cannot see the Bedrock skins from your Java player's perspective, it may be that the skin is still in the queue waiting to be uploaded. Wait a day or so and check again.

Comment: ["Mc servers top"](https://mcservers.top/bedrockandjavacrossplay/) is a fairly good resource for finding servers for this, and possibly your next favourite server!