# Can you transfer pocket edition skin to java edition made in-game character creator?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

bedrock java edition skin game

Comment: I have actually asked and answered this question here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/385166/233666
This method is supposedly not working though, according to @aytimothy

Comment: @pinckerman That's the one I just linked

Comment: @Diehe I know, I voted the question as duplicate using your link and the system posted that canned comment.

Comment: @pinckerman Ah ok, sorry about that.