# Can I use my Minecraft skin on switch version

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a custom Minecraft skin for my game on the Mac, but I’d like to use this skin on the Switch too. Is there any way for me to do this?

Comment: We have a question that's for the other way around https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371742/can-i-use-my-bedrock-skin-in-the-java-edition I'm not sure if that may provide some insight or not.